# How to read a text file from the last line in C++?

Tags: c++, ifstream

I have a text file like this:

```
1    0.05   -7  
2    0.1    -4  
3    0.11   -1   
4    0.12   -3   
3    0.15   -2
4    0.2    0  
5    0.25   8
```

What I am looking for is to read the text file in C++ from the last line, reach the line which starts with 4, save the values of this line in an array, then continue to reach the line, which starts with 2 and again save the values corresponding to this line.

It is very important for me to start from the last line, since I look for the last updated values for time step 4.
Reading from the beginning gives me this vector `4 0.12 -3` while I am looking for this vector `4 0.2 0`

Comment: you have to do it continuously, or once sometimes?

Comment: I need to do it at the beginning of each time step, so its once sometimes.

Comment: @user3636322 do you favor memory over speed or vice versa? what speaks against just parsing the whole file at once and work with that intermediate data? will you have to re-parse the whole file always or is there some append going on somewhere?

Comment: @user3636322 do the lines have a variable length or are they written out padded?

Comment: all the lines have the same number of column, and it is better to do it as fast as possible...

Answer (score 2):

There's really no trivial way to do this. Unless the file is absolutely enormous (100MGB or more), the best approach is probably to simply read the entire content into a vector, and process it in memory [in whatever order you choose, as you can now treat it as a vector of whatever type it is, and thus "random access"].

It is possible to "move backwards from the end", but it's awkward. Something like this would read the entire file from back to front:

```
ifstream f("somefile.txt");
char c;
// Place get position at one from last. 
f.seekg(-1, ios_base::end);
while(f.get(c))
{
  ... process character ... 
  // Move back two (because get moved forward one, and
  // we want the one before that. 
  f.seekg(-2, ios_base::cur);
}
```

You then have to bear in mind that your string comes in backwards, so you have to prepend instead of append.

Answer (score 1):

My strategy for a spot operation would be scan all the file line by line keeping an array of two lines in memory, updated at each incoming line in order to contain always the latest two lines. At `EOF` your array contains the interested lines.
Pseudocode:

```
array[2];
array[0]=array[1]=null;
while(!eof)
{
   array[1]=array[0];
   array[0]=readline();
}

... do what you want with array[1] and array[0]
```

`array[0]` will contain the last line of your file, `array[1]` the one but last. 
check for null: if the file contains just one line, or no lines at all, you can have one or both the entries in the array pointing to null.
Of course this is time expensive if the file is very big in size, but it's a simple reliable solution for a spot operation with an order of magnitude of at least some minutes between each operations.
Otherwise, if more frequent polling is needed, why dont continuosly monitor the file? 
This is kind a strategy used by `tail -f` programs.

Answer (score 0):

Jumping around in a text file is difficult and usually highly inefficient. I suggest the following:

1. Load the whole file into memory, keeping only the most recent result:

   ```
   ifstream fin("fname.txt");

   // ... Don't forget error checking.

   std::unordered_map<int, std::pair<float, int>> entries;
   int first, third;
   float second;
   while (fin >> first >> second >> third) {
      entries[first] = make_pair(second, third); // Will overwrite existing.
   }
   ```
2. Now you can easily access the last entry simply by accessing the map for the key you are looking for.

   ```
   cout << entries[4]->first << " " << entries[4]->second  << endl;
   ```

Will output: 0.2 0

Answer (score 0):

Two strategies come to mind:

1-The previous proposed: have array of size 2 or two variables, etc..., to save last two lines read (should work very well if the file is small, and is really straight forward)
2-Using ifstream::seekg(std::ios_base::end) to positionated in the EOF, and search backwards for EOL markers (this should work if file is big and lines are small compared to file). With peek could check for EOL markers (this is more complex taking into account different EOL markers (\n\r, \n, \r), and possibly slow if lines are to long.